# OpenCV и запись в RTMP-поток

Tags: c++, opencv, rtmp

Мое приложение считывает кадры из rtmp-потока используя функцию cv::VideoCapture, модифицирует их, и записывает измененные кадры в видеофайл используя cv::VideoWriter. Теперь мне нужно изменить приложение и вместо файла записывать измененные кадры в другой rtmp-поток. Кто-нибудь может объяснить мне как это можно сделать? В настоящий момент я использую gcc5 и OpenCV 2.4.13.

Answer (score 1):

Сделаю предположение, что раз вычитывается поток RTMP, то уже используется FFmpeg. Собственно и используйте его же возможности для публикации RTMP потока на удалённый сервер.

Т.е. средсвами OpenCV нужно сформировать данные, которые положить в AVFrame, потом закодировать и записать в муксер, примеры можно посмотреть: http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/examples.html, конкретно: http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/muxing_8c-example.html

Т.е. самый нюанс: это переход от фрейма OpenCV к AVFrame FFmpeg. Но там ничего сложного.

**Upd**: как и обещал - про переход. Не знаю, насколько полезным будет информация.

Полный код не привожу, так как там много контекста. Если что просто буду добавлять комментарии, что и откуда.

Итак, переход от `AVFrame` к `cv::Mat`:

```
// Здесь используется AvCpp (находится на GitHub), если коротко, то результат
// recvFrame.raw() -> AVFrame *
const int lineWidth   = inFrame.raw()->linesize[0];
uint8_t  *data        = inFrame.raw()->data[0];
...
// тут всё понятно: .height() и .width() возвращают высотку картинки в пикселях, CV_8UC3 задаёт тип семпла
// ну а data - это нужная область данных.
cv::Mat imgInp {inFrame.height(), inFrame.width(), CV_8UC3, data}; // оборачиваем входную картинку в формат понятный OpenCV
cv::Mat img {imgInp.size(), imgInp.type()};                        //
cv::cvtColor(imgInp, img, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);                      // а тут уже новая картинка сделанная из входной, но в желаемом формате
                                                                   // по идее работать можно уже и с imgInp, если формат пикселя устраивает
```

Стоит учитывать несколько нюансов:

- форматы бывают пакованные (например, RGB24, YUY2), тогда они записываются в одну плоскость в `data[0]`, а могут быть планарными, типа YUV420, тогда плоскости распределяются по `data[0]...data[N-1]`, 
  где `N` - число плоскостей (`N==1` частный случай - пакованный формат, а так бывают 2 (NV12, встречаются реже) или 3 (YUV420, чаще)). FFmpeg, что бы не мучать пользователя, выделяет под планары тоже
  непрерывный блок памяти и просто правильно расставляет указатели на плоскости, выходит:

  ```
  auto ptr = ...; // тут какое-то выделение памяти
  data[0] = ptr;
  data[1] = ptr + offset_0;
  data[2] = ptr + offset_1;
  ```

  т.е. отсюда видно, что `data[0]` указывает на начало блока. Таким образом:

  ```
  uint8_t  *data        = inFrame.raw()->data[0];
  ```

  легитимно для любых форматов. Но при дальнейшем переходе к OpenCV нужно помнить и делать корректные преобразования.
- ширина линии (`lineWidth`) нужна для выровненных данных. Это требования кодеков, обычно. Т.е.

  ```
  line_1 != line_0 + imageWidth; // пусть будет 1 байт на пиксель
  // но
  line_1 == line_0 + lineWidth[0];
  ```

  индекс - соответствует индексу плоскости. Для разных плоскостей может отличаться.

Переход от `cv::Mat` к `AVFrame` делается аналогичным образом. За одним но: что бы быть гарантированно уверенными в выравнивании, лучше сначала сформировать `AVFrame`, после чего получить указатели и завернуть это добро в `cv::Mat`,
как это было описано выше и работать уже с этой картинкой средсвами OpenCV: так как данные общие все воздействия через OpenCV отразятся и на `AVFrame`.

Сам фрейм можно сформировать как-то так:

```
auto frame = av_frame_alloc();
frame->format = pixelFormat;
frame->width  = width;
frame->height = height;
av_frame_get_buffer(frame, align); // тут выравнивание, 1 или 32 может пройти в большинстве случаев

// Всё, сейчас всё, что нужно аллоцированно, теперь можно делать переход к cv::Mat
...

// Работаем с OpenCV
...

// Кодируем frame, засылаем его в Muxer
...

// после работы с фреймом
av_frame_unref(frame);
```

Если хочется избежать копирования, то нужно более дательно читать документацию на OpenCV и FFmpeg:

- https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.0/frame_8c.html

  - можно посмотреть как сделано у меня в AvCpp заворачание буферов в AVFrame:

    - https://github.com/h4tr3d/avcpp/blob/master/src/frame.cpp#L97

      - здесь данные копируются, но если убрать шаг с `av_frame_get_buffer()`, то после `av_image_fill_arrays()` достаточно сделать:

        ```
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 4 && buf[i]; ++i) {
            m_raw->data[i] = buf[i];
            m_raw->linesize[i] = linesize[i];
        }
        ```
- http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a

  - тут `step` - это аналог `linesize`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: у меня просто был прототип видео процессора, который читал при помощи FFmpeg, делал обработку при помощи OpenCV и дальше стримил на nginx-rtmp. К сожалению - POPI. Но вытянуть переход от AVFrame к OpenCV и обратно сегодня смогу.

Comment: Был бы весьма благодарен

Comment: По поводу перехода от FVFrame к cv::Mat. В принципе, мне это не нужно вообще, ибо cv::VideoCapture мне из RTMP-потока  и так возвращает cv::Mat. Проблема в том, что cv::VideoWriter напрямую в RTMP-поток писать не умеет

Comment: Да, но ЕМНИП, поддержка video, стримов в OpenCV делается средствами FFmpeg. Поэтому на выходе используйте его же, т.е. напрямую, без посредника в лице cv::VideoWriter. Все эти переходы просто как справочный материал, как перейти к AVFrame, что бы дальше запроцессить при помощи FFmpeg. Причём, если аккуратно, если в Mat правильные падинги используются, то можно вообще без лишнего копирования перейти к фрейму.

Comment: А как этот AVFrame в RTMP засунуть?

Comment: С точки зрения FFmpeg открываете rtmp://xxxx (создаёте инстанс AVFormatContext), потом добавляете туда стримы (AVStream), указываете кодек и открываете его (инстанс AVCodeContext), потом кодируете AVFrame в AVPacket и пакет муксуете в AVFormatContext. Посмотрите пример по ссылке в начале и вообще примеры в FFmpeg.